# JOOQ record mapper maps the wrong id on join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have two tables, asdf and qwer, both tables have a primary key named "id". When I join these two tables, the result will have two columns named id, and JOOQ is unable to map the records correctly to POJOs.

```
sql.select(ASDF.fields())
.select(QWER.fields())
.from(ASDF)
.leftOuterJoin(QWER).onKey(QWER.ASDF_ID)
.where(ASDF.SOMETHING.eq(something))
.fetch(r -> tuple(r.into(Asdf.class), r.into(Qwer.class)))
```

Now every Asdf instance has the same id as it's corresponding Qwer instance in the tuple.

Is there a clever aliasing trick that can solve this problem, or did I miss something in the JOOQ documentation, or is this a bug in JOOQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`DefaultRecordMapper`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) maps [`Record`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html) columns to POJO attributes by column name. Even if the two `ID` columns may have distinct table references associated to them in the `Record` (`ASDF.ID` vs. `QWER.ID`), there is no such table information available in the POJO.

One workaround would be to map `r` to the respective `TableRecord` first, using [`Record.into(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-org.jooq.Table-):

```
r -> tuple(
    r.into(ASDF).into(Asdf.class), 
    r.into(QWER).into(Qwer.class)
)
```

Comment: Danke schön! Could you please put a link in your answer, that points to the relevant part of the documentation?

Comment: @kazmer: It's already linked, see [`DefaultRecordMapper`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html)

Comment: Where is the `tuple` coming from?

Comment: @JonasGröger: Good point. The OP is probably using [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) along with jOOQ. There's a static import of would be [`org.jooq.lambda.Tuple.tuple`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOOλ/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html#tuple-T1-T2-), then